# Right-clicking a Bootstrap button will not display correct context menu in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, navigation, contextmenu

My client wants their navigation links to look like an image button. This is simple enough with Bootstrap, I just add the `btn` class to the link and embed a Font Awesome icon. The problem is that right-clicking the "button" in IE does not show the proper context menu when you right-click the image (for Open in new tab). If you right click to the side of the image it works as expected. It also works as expected in Chrome no matter where you click. Is there a work around for IE?

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="http://jsfiddle.net/"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-2x"></i></a>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v79oknb4/2/

**Update**: I'm talking about IE 9.

Comment: I just checked it in IE9, 10 and 11... seems to work just fine for me

Comment: I'm using IE 9 and it's not working for me. I'm talking about right clicking the icon to open in a new tab. When I do it in IE9 I get the same menu as if I'm clicking on the page background.

Comment: Perhaps it worked for me since I checked it using IE11 in IE9 emulation mode.

Comment: @Homer Were you able to over come this issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, I have not found a workaround.